# How to set id/class when I have an unkown number of divs

Tags: javascript, css

Depending on how many rows my sql query returns I will create divs to present the data.

Every div needs to have an unique id but I do not know how to do this efficiently.

Right now I have defined a couple of id's but this can't possibly be the right way to do it.

#myid1, #myid2, #myid3, myid4 { }

This will not work if I get more rows.

What is the best/correct way to do this?

Comment: Give them all a common class instead (or only give a class/id to the *table*, and select something like `#mytable tr`)

Comment: why do they needs ids?

Comment: If you are creating those <div>s in a loop, you can use the loop's index for this. However string-composing an ID like that is bad practice, use `data-id="x"` instead.

Comment: Is there a unique primary key returned with the data you get back?  You could use that to make an ID for your divs, and that way each div will have a meaningful connection with your data in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this CSS selector to select any div element with an ID that **starts with** 'myid':

```
div[id^="myid"] { ... }
```

---

If you want to automatically assign unique ID's to your elements, you could use JavaScript (nodeList is an array of your elements)

Ancient JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) { //loop through every element in your array
    nodeList[i].id = 'myid' + i; //set element ID to 'myid' + current index
}
```

ES6:

```
nodeList.forEach((item, i) => { //loop through every element in your array
    item.id = 'myid' + i; //set element ID to 'myid' + current index
});
```

Your generated ID's will be 'myid0', 'myid1', 'myid2' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "class" instead of "ID" beacuse you dont know how much row is there.when you have to apply same css on more than one element than you have to use "class".

you can also use id and class aplly id on parent div and class on sub div.

like

```
#row_container .row{
}
```

here   **#row_container** is  parent div and **.row** is child div

if you don't want to apply a css on that row than simply you have to genrate dayanmic id's.